# Cross origin requests are only supported for protocol schemes: http, data, chrome, chrome-extension, https

Tags: jquery

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $.ajax({
        url: 'https://swapi.co/api/people/1/?format=json',
        type:'GET',
        dataType: 'JSON',
        success: function(json){
            console.log(json.name);
            $("h2.name").text(json.name);
        }
    });

    const ITERACIONES_1=6;
    const ITERACIONES_2=3;
    let helper= {
      film:'',
      counter:0,
      method: function (per,res) {
        this.film += res.title;
        this.counter++;
        if (this.counter == (ITERACIONES_1 * ITERACIONES_2)) {
          for (var index = 0; index < ITERACIONES_1; index++) {
            var a = $("<div data-toggle='modal' data-target='#myModal'" + 
            "onclick=\"data2('"+this.film+"')\" class='col-md-4'>" +
          per.results[index].name + "</div>");
          $(".row").append(a);
          console.log(per.results[index].name);
          }
          $(".btnNext").attr("id", per.next);
        }
      }
    };

    $.ajax({
            url: 'https://swapi.co/api/people/?format=json',
            type:'GET',
            dataType: 'JSON',
            success: function(per){
                $(".row").empty();
                var film;
                for (var i = 0; i < ITERACIONES_1; i++) {
                    for (var index = 0; index < ITERACIONES_2; index++) {
                        var ul = per.results[i].films[index];
                        $.ajax({
                            url:ul,
                            type: 'GET',
                            dataType: 'JSON',
                            success:function(res){
                                helper.method(per,res);
                            }
                        }); 
                    } 
                }
            }
        });

        $(".btnNext").click(function(){
            var a = $(".btnNext").attr("id");
            $.ajax({
                url: a,
                type:'GET',
                dataType: 'JSON',
                success: function(per){
                    var film;
                    for (var i = 0; i < ITERACIONES_1; i++) {
                        for (var index = 0; index < ITERACIONES_2; index++) {
                            var ul = per.results[i].films[index];
                            $.ajax({
                                url:ul,
                                type: 'GET',
                                dataType: 'JSON',
                                success:function(res){
                                    helper.method(per,res);
                                }
                            }); 
                        } 
                    }
                }
            });

        });




});

function data2(nom){
    //alert(nom);
    $(".modal-body > p").remove();
    $(".modal-body").append("<p>"+nom+"</p>");  
}
```

al ejecutar el evento clic, me marca este error

> jquery.min.js:4 Failed to load
>   file:///C:/Users/Emma/Desktop/test/starwars.html#: Cross origin
>   requests are only supported for protocol schemes: http, data, chrome,
>   chrome-extension, https.

Comment: Haz intentado agregar crossDomain: true en tu $.ajax ?

Comment: Ya lo agregué pero me arca el mismo error

Comment: @ErnestoEmmanuelYahLopez, En `file:///` también he tenido este problema (intentaba probar un servicio web hecho en C# "WCF"). Lo que hice fue crear un sitio en Internet Information Services.

Comment: hablas de ponerlo en un servidor web?

Comment: Cual es el id del botón que se guarda en la variable a ?

Comment: $(".btnNext").attr("id", per.next); en esta parte yo le agrego una caracteristica que viene del JSON el cual es una URL

Comment: Y cual es esa url ?

Comment: https://swapi.co/api/people/?format=json&page=2

Comment: pero si tiene el https solo que en los comentarios no lo muestra

Comment: @Ernesto Emmanuel Yah Lopez estás ejecutando la aplicación desde un servidor? Este puede ser uno de los motivos. Si es el caso, intenta meterlo en un apache por ejemplo a ver que tal.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

En principio lo que te está diciendo es que estás intentando acceder a archivos que están en un servidor "externo".

En una página leí un par de formas de "saltarse" esa restricción, te la pongo aquí y le das un vistazo.

[Abrir página local con Ajax](http://www.regochan.com/varios/item/105-abrir-pagina-local-con-ajax-en-chrome.html)

En ella habla de dos formas de hacerlo, que son:

- Cerrar todas las páginas de Chrome (si no, no funciona), abrir la consola de comandos, y escribir esta ruta, que en el caso de Windows es **"C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe" --allow-file-access-from-files**. Según la versión de Windows que tengas, deberás quitar el (x86) del nombre. Una vez hecho esto, podrás ejecutarlo. Cuando cierres la ventana, deberás volver a repetir los pasos.
- Utilizar Internet Explorer (no recomendada).

Espero que te funcione.

Comment: Si, lo que estoy intentando hacer es una llamada a una API externa

Comment: ¿Pero te ha funcionado?

Comment: si me funcionó gracias